# Launch TorBrowser or Tor enabled Firefox browser in RSelenium

Tags: r, selenium, firefox, tor, rselenium

**How do you launch TorBrowser in RSelenium?**

I tried this to no avail:

```
library(RSelenium)
browserP <- "C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/Tor Browser/Browser/firefox.exe"
jArg <- paste0("-Dwebdriver.firefox.bin=\"", browserP, "\"")
pLoc <- "C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/Tor Browser/Browser/TorBrowser/Data/Browser/profile.meek-http-helper/"
jArg <- c(jArg, paste0("-Dwebdriver.firefox.profile=\"", pLoc, "\""))
selServ <- RSelenium::startServer(javaargs = jArg)


Error: startServer is now defunct. Users in future can find the function in 
file.path(find.package("RSelenium"), "examples/serverUtils"). The
recommended way to run a selenium server is via Docker. Alternatively
see the RSelenium::rsDriver function.
```

`rsDriver` doesn't take a `javaargs` argument, and I can't figure out how to get this to work either:

```
fprof <- getFirefoxProfile("C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/Tor Browser/Browser/TorBrowser/Data/Browser/profile.meek-http-helper/", useBase = T)
remDr <- remoteDriver(extraCapabilities = list(marionette = TRUE))
```